# hiding duplicated cells along with their entire rows,

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a range of data set with 3 columns, as given below.

```
0 abc def
0 geh ijk
0 lmn nop
5 qrs tuv
5 wxy zab
5 cde fgh
10 ab cd
10 ef gh
10 ij kl
```

in the first column we have 0, 5 and 10..... being repeated.

i want to keep just first value along with entire row and hide remaining duplicated 0,5,10.....

i have long range of data set and each value in the first column has 9 duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub hide_duplicates()
Dim OneCell As Range
For Each OneCell In Range("A2:A10") ' data range
    If OneCell.Value = OneCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        OneCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub hideDupes()

   dim r as range

   with worksheets("sheet1")
       for each r in .range(.cells(1, "a"), .cells(.rows.count, "a").end(xlup))
           r.entirerow.hidden = cbool(r.row > application.match(r.value, .range("a:a"), 0))
        next r
    end with

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Advanced Filter` with a formula criteria:

```
=COUNTIF(A8:$A$8,A8)=1
```

#### Before

[image]

#### Adv Filter Dialog

[image]

#### After

[image]